# Leaflet contextmenu is not working or responding to events

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

(Posting this for fellow noobs who might make the same mistake as me...)

I combined two github projects: Leaflet.contextmenu with the bootleaf project.

I started with bootleaf and added `<script>, <link>` to the index.html.  Since I was using the bootleaf index.html, it already had the `<script src=".../app.js">` where the map was created:

```
map = L.map("map", { ... });
```

Unfortunately, I added the dist/leaflet.contextmenu.js and src/Map.ContextMenu.js files also but added them AFTER app.js.  This caused the code to not be initialized (since it is a plug-in).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to get the right order for the  like thus:

```
  <script src="node_modules/leaflet-contextmenu/dist/leaflet.contextmenu.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/leaflet-contextmenu/src/Map.ContextMenu.js"></script>

  <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
```